# Bootstrap navbar not showing collapse div and navbar-nav list

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Trying to make a navbar in bootstrap. The header is taking all the space and the collapse div is not showing. While I have typed the exact code from the tutorial where all the output is generated perfectly. What have I done wrong? Bootstrap beginner here.

I created a nav tag with a navbar-hear and navbar-collapse div with two  lists for options on navbar

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="nav navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Recipe Book</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav nav">
        <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shopping</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Manage <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <li><a href="#">Save Data</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fetch Data</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The navbar-nav elements are not visible and if I remove collapse class they are just appearing below the navbar-header which is taking too much space anyway.

Comment: have you linked bootstrap js and css and also jquery?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#supported-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do ? There some class that you have used where it is not needed.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Recipe Book</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav nav">
      <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Shopping</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Manage
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Save Data</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fetch Data</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>

</nav>
```